# How to add structured report to DicomDirectory in fo dicom?

Tags: fo-dicom

For Fo-Dicom in C#, I am trying to add a structured report to DicomDirectory object using AddFile API.
But the report is getting added as an image, is there any way to correct this?
If at all it is not possible how to do it by manually adding DicomTags information to DicomDirectory class object?
Can you show some examples?

Answer (score 0):

you actually found a bug in fo-dicom. This is the ticket: https://github.com/fo-dicom/fo-dicom/issues/1045

In this ticket there is also a workaround until the next release is available:

```
var dd = new DicomDirectory();
var directoryEntry = dd.AddFile(datasetWithReport);
// now directoryEntry has 4 properties that link to the 4 datasets in each hierachy. there you can change or add values
if (directoryEntry.InstanceRecord.GetString(DicomTag.DirectoryRecordType) == "IMAGE")
{
    directoryEntry.InstanceRecord.AddOrUpdate(DicomTag.DirectoryRecordType, "REPORT");
    // reports remore some more entries
    directoryEntry.InstanceRecord.AddOrUpdate(DicomTag.CompletionFlag, 1);
    directoryEntry.InstanceRecord.AddOrUpdate(DicomTag.VerificationFlag, 0);
    // ....
}
```

So after calling `AddFile` you get a entry-object that points to all entries in all 4 levels. so you can change/update some things afterwards.

Please also add your comments and thougts also in the github issue.